# Get share link of files in specific folder of OneDrive

Tags: vba, onedrive

Can anyone give me an example of VBA (Excel) code for get share links (edit) for each file in specific folder in OneDrive?
Or a useful link?

Thanks
Tudor

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for, but maybe it is this...

```
Sub GetFolder_Data_Collection()

Range("A:L").ClearContents
Range("A1").Value = "Name"
Range("B1").Value = "Path"
Range("C1").Value = "Size (KB)"
Range("D1").Value = "DateLastModified"
Range("E1").Value = "Attributes"
Range("F1").Value = "DateCreated"
Range("G1").Value = "DateLastAccessed"
Range("H1").Value = "Drive"
Range("I1").Value = "ParentFolder"
Range("J1").Value = "ShortName"
Range("K1").Value = "ShortPath"
Range("L1").Value = "Type"
Range("A1").Select

Dim strPath As String
'strPath = "I:\Information Security\KRI Monthly Data Collection\"
strPath = GetFolder

Dim OBJ As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object

Set OBJ = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = OBJ.GetFolder(strPath)

Call ListFiles(Folder)

Dim SubFolder As Object

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(SubFolder)
    Call GetSubFolders(SubFolder)
Next SubFolder


End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub ListFiles(ByRef Folder As Object)

On Error Resume Next
For Each File In Folder.Files
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell = File.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = File.Path
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Address:=File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Path
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = (File.Size / 1024) 'IN KB
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = File.DateLastModified
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = File.Attributes
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = File.DateCreated
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = File.DateLastAccessed
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = File.Drive
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = File.ParentFolder
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = File.ShortName
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = File.ShortPath
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) = File.Type
Next File

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub GetSubFolders(ByRef SubFolder As Object)

Dim FolderItem As Object
On Error Resume Next
For Each FolderItem In SubFolder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(FolderItem)
    Call GetSubFolders(FolderItem)
Next FolderItem

End Sub


Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, ryguy72, and thanks for the quick response. I have multiple files (300+) (.xlsx) in a OneDrive folder. I want to get a share-link for editing for each file. Each link will be mailed to a specific person (different files - different people)  so he can open and edit that one with ExcelOnline. I think **I need a model for using the OneDrve API with VBA**.

Answer (score 0):

That's a completely different thing.  If you want to email different files to different people, setup an Excel 'template' according to your specific needs, and run the script below.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
 In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: I will describe the situation in more detail. (Sorry for my English, I played football during English classes.). I have a template and I have written the code that generates a file for each person. I saved these files in OnDrive (local synchronized folder). **Now I want to write a code (VBA-Excel) that extracts from OneDrive a share-link for editing for each generated file.** I would like an example code for authentication in OneDrive and call the OneDrve API to return one share-link for editing, for each file in that folder. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to email different files to different people, see the script below.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people

In column B : E-mail addresses

In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```